# JavaScript needle.put object not being parsed

Tags: javascript, node.js

Folks, trying to `put` the following object using the `needle.js` library:

```
var object = {
    fName: 'Jasmine',
    lName: 'Tests'
}

    var options = {
        json: true,
        accept: 'application/json'
    }

    needle.put(url, object, options, function (err, resp, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log ('post error',err);
            callback (err, null);
        } else {
            console.log ("RETURNED", body)
            callback (null, resp, body);
        }
    })
```

I get back:

```
RETURNED { code: 'InternalError', message: 'Unexpected token o' }
```

The Express API tries to do a `JSON.parse()` on an incoming request and fails.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your response of that url.

Comment: `url` is fine, i just have not filled it into stackoverflow

Comment: I mean the response which is parsed failed.

Comment: @xdazz thats the reqponse right off the function, unparsed